# Using manager for controlling the volume

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

[image]

I am having problem with using audio manager for controlling volume 
I am making a simple app to change ringer mode from the app but the app is crashing. The way  to get instance of audio manager as directed by google is showing error. Is it possible to access and control ringer volume and mode from app?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean isPhoneSilent;
private AudioManager audioManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    Button toggle_Btn = findViewById(R.id.toggle_Btn);

    int ringerMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
    if(ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
    {
        isPhoneSilent=true;
    }
    else

    toggle_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isPhoneSilent)
            {
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                isPhoneSilent=false;
            }else
            {
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                isPhoneSilent=true;
            }
        }
    });





}
```

Comment: First provide code here not on image. Second did you try `getSystemServices` without using `Context`

Comment: You do not need `Context` before `getSystemService()` as you are  in an activity that has Context

Comment: Yes I tried it without context also but still the app is crashing i have added my main_actvity.java code

Comment: Please add complete stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: There is no exception only the app is crashing